# How to access the entity inside the buildForm method of a form

Tags: forms, symfony, get, entity

I'm trying to get the entity inside the own form. I lazy remember a getData() method, but it doesn't exist inside the form, and I can't remember how to use it.

Is there any way to get the entity inside the buildform method not using an event listener?

I mean, something like this:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
        /*some method to get the entity of the form such as getEntity????????*/
        $builder->add('field');
   }
```

Comment: Please see this answer [symfony 2.3 form getData doesn't work in subforms collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870866/symfony-2-3-form-getdata-doesnt-work-in-subforms-collections/52997469#52997469)

Answer (score 85):

I found it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
        $entity = $builder->getData();
        $builder->add('field');
   }
```

Comment: Please note that if you are using type in collection you need to use form events


$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function   (FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {

            /** @var YourEntity $data */

            $data = $event->getData();

});

Comment: @nvvetal Your comment made my day :) Thanks. 

Additionality if you want to modify builder inside event do `$form = $event->getForm()` and than `$form->add`

Comment: Thanks! 1 hours I'm findinga solution.... symfony documenation is not always complete :)